# How to "export" bones from Blender to Unity?

Tags: armature, unity

I created some controller bones for a camera, so it can rotate in all directions a normal camera would:

[image]

But when I export it to Unity, the bones cannot be used. What can I do differently so the camera can be controlled in Unity in some way?

Comment: Control bones that control other bones or are just a parent for the mesh might not work in game engines. AFAIK you need to export the deform bones of a rig.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry but I don't understand the second part. What are deform bones and how do I get them?

Comment: I've assumed that you have bound the mesh directly to the bones. Sorry, I should have asked for confirmation first. So, how have you bound the mesh to the armature? Deform bones are bones that have the [X] Deform checkbox enabled. The setting is in the *Bone Properties*. These bones move and deform the mesh. Their influence is defined by vertex groups assigned to the mesh. For a quick test you can make the armature the parent of the mesh with *Parent To>With Automatic Weights* and check if it moves. Deformation will be horrible. You need to assign the mesh parts to the vertex groups to fix it

Comment: Oh yes I actually did that and I can move it in Blender but we want to move it in Unity too. So that the camera follows the player around. Can we do that somehow?

Comment: I'm sure you can do this. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Unity rigs. Maybe someone else here knows. Or you can ask this in a Unity forum?